# Give an example of smooth function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ such that supp $f=[0,1]$ and $|f'(x)|\leq1$ for all $x$.

Tags: real-analysis, differential-topology

Give an example of smooth function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ such that

supp $f=[0,1]$ and $|f'(x)|\leq1$ for all $x$.

Comment: What does supp $f=[0,1]$ mean?

Comment: @Vikrant Desai The support of $f$ is the closure of the set $\{x : f(x) \neq 0\}$.

Comment: Am I missing something? or a function that only "lifts a little" from the x axis in $[0,1]$ does the job...

Comment: Try something of the form $e^{-1/t^2}$ and paste it with itself (I don't know if this makes sense to you as to me).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take your favorite smooth function $g$ which is supported on $[0,1]$.

$|g'|$, being continuous on $[0,1]$, will be bounded. Let $M$ be such a bound. Consider now $f:=\frac{g}{M}$.

If you want an explicit example, just pick a particular $g$ and follow the procedure.

Comment: how to get this $g$??

Comment: @Eklavya Based on your question, I imagine you have already encountered the so-called *bump functions*, which are compactly supported smooth functions. If not, the construction is standard and found in any book of differential topology for example (and also in a lot of questions in this site). Having a compactly supported smooth function $h$ on $\mathbb{R}$, consider a interval $[-a,a]$ which contains its support. Now, you can for example define $g$ by $g(x)=f(2ax-a)$.

Answer (score 1):

This type of functions are to be constructed. for example $$f(x)=\left\{
                 \begin{array}{ll}
                 e^\frac{-1}{1-x^2}  , & \hbox{$ |x|\leq$ 1;} \\
                  0 , & \hbox{otherwise}
                 \end{array}
               \right.,$$ 
Using the fact that $e^\frac{-1}{x^2}$ approches $0$ when x approches $0.$ $\sin x, \cos x$ can also be used to construct this type of functions.